# Table view gets cut off when rotating a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, uinavigationcontroller

My UITableView, actually all my subview, when i rotate the UINavigationController that is their parent.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't set the autoresizing masks of your views correctly (either in code or in Interface Builder).